# Missing required architecture arm64 in file issue when update Xcode to 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.3

Today i updated `XCode to 7.3`,and my project can not build success any more.But i can build success on `Xcode 7.2`

And i got following message:

> ld: in '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation', missing required architecture arm64 in file /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation (2 slices) for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: did you fix this issue? getting same issue

Comment: I'm sorry.no,I got back to Xcode7.2.do you fix?

Comment: Yes. for me fixed by deleting unwanted framework from project workspace.go in finder check any unwanted framework. clean and run.

Comment: ok.thanks for sharing.

Comment: Does it work for you?